# Should you lean your body into the corner or away from the corner while cornering in a motorbike?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life

We can observe MotoGP racers leaning their torsos towards the inside of the corners while taking on a turn, whereas, police motorcyclists usually do the opposite (i.e. hold their torsos counter to the bike's lean). How can we justify these two different approaches to the same problem of cornering on a bike?

A solution that explains the dynamics and kinematics of these two approaches, and why one should be better than the other would be appreciated.

Comment: More on [countersteering](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=countersteering+is%3Aq).

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, as Bird's answer points out.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Here is my best guess as to what your intention is. There is the lean of the motorbike itself, and there is the position of the rider relative to the motorbike. MotoGP racers reposition their body to shift the center of mass of the motorbike/rider assembly. The center of mass is shifted towards the inside of the corner. In non-racing cases: there is a riding style where the rider corners as follows: the motorbike itself is made to lean into the corner, but the torso of the rider is held counter to that lean. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @Cleonis Thank you for your comment. I've edited the question to make it a bit intelligible.

Comment: Before answering a question, one must have a clear question. There are 2 primary modes of steering a motorcycle: low speed, where the vehicle is NOT yet gyroscopically stabilized, and the wheel is turned into the direction of the desired turn, and high speed, where countersteer initiates lean and steering into the opposite direction of the front wheel. Obviously, if a m/c is not stabilized at slow speed, a counter-leaning rider is needed to keep balance. At high speed, the m/c balances itself, and the rider can lean-in, neutral lean, or counter-lean, and the m/c will still balance and turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While cornering, the radius of the turn is given by.

$$r = \frac{w\cos \left (\theta \right )}{\delta \cos \left (\phi \right )}$$

[image]

where $w$ is the wheelbase, $\theta$ is the lean angle, $\delta$ is the steer angle, and $\phi$ is the rake/caster angle of the steering axis. The wheelbase and rake are almost constant (slightly increase while accelerating and decrease while braking). The lean angle and steer angle are the major variables that dictate the radius of turn.

[image]

Consider the above situation where the lean angle of the bike is $\theta$ and the steer angle is $\phi$, and they dictate a turning radius $r$ . The bike is traveling at a velocity $v$ and the mass of the whole system is $m$.
The weight of the system acts along its center of mass and is balanced by the normal force. The frictional force provides the necessary centripetal force for cornering. Here you can see that the normal and centripetal forces produce torques about the center of mass and these two torques act in the opposite direction. If the rider is able to corner by maintaining this lean angle $\theta$ constant throughout the turn (i.e., without falling to the ground or being pushed to the normal), the two torques must balance each other.

$$tan\theta = \frac {f} {N}$$
$$tan\theta = \frac {v^2} {rg}$$

[image]

Now, consider the above situation, where the rider leans his torso away from the turn (which we will refer to as counter-leaning from here onwards). The lean angle of the bike has increased to $\alpha$. To maintain the radius of the turn the same as before, the rider has now decreased the steering angle. Assume the bike is still traveling at the same velocity $v$ and the lean angle of the center of mass of the system has not changed from $\theta$. Then, the following condition still holds true.
$$tan\theta = \frac {v^2} {rg}$$
Thus the rider can still make that turn without falling to the ground. But this time he stays in a more comfortable up-right position.

From here, you can also workout the dynamics when the rider instead leans his upper body further into the corner than his bike.

All in all, you can approach the same turn with the same velocity in three different ways. To answer your question of which one of the approaches is better, there's no definite answer. If you are a MotoGP racer, your tires are subject to extreme wear. In that case you'd like your bike to be as straight as possible to increase the area of the contact patch so that the wear gets distributed to a larger area and the co-efficient of friction of your tires doesn't decrease drastically with time. If you were to counter lean instead, then the edge of your tires would wear off fast and you will be prone to falling off while cornering later.

However, if you are a daily commuter, and your tires are not subject to massive frictional forces, it would be better if you counter-lean during turns because that would increase your range of vision. Life-saving swerves on the road are also quicker when you counter lean.

**Addendum**

Since we are talking about safe cornering approaches, I'd to add something that might be useful for fellow riders.

Whenever we see a corner ahead, we engage the brakes to slow the bike to a speed in which we are comfortable turning ($v^2 \alpha r$). We then let off the brakes and then proceed with the cornering. However, what is even better is if we just ease off the rear brake, while continuing to drag/trail the front brake. This is because when we are decelerating, the caster angle and trail length of the bike decreases, making it easier for us to steer the handlebar. Continuous deceleration would also result in a lower speed, enabling us to make tighter turns in cases of emergency, especially in blind corners. Once the exit of the corner is visible, the rider can now give some throttle (increase velocity of the bike to increase the centripetal force torque) along with counter-steering to make his bike stand straight.

*Why should one trail brake with the front brake only?*

While braking, the weight of the bike shifts to the front tire, decreasing the maximum friction the rear tire can generate without slipping. The tire you brake on is also the one that actually generates the frictional force for linear deceleration (which is greater in magnitude than the accelerating frictional force generated by the other tire). Since, both the radial centripetal force and tangential decelerating force are sourced from the friction on the tire, at certain braking point, the rear tire is bound to slip. The centripetal force won't be enough to maintain a steady cornering radius, and the rear of the bike would thus drift away from the corner. The torque due to the normal force would be greater than that due to the centripetal force, and the bike would fall into the corner.
However, at this point, most bikers would suddenly let go of the rear brake as a last ditch effort. This would then restore traction on the rear tire, and the torque due to the frictional force would cause the bike to stand straight and beyond. This, together with the rebounding rear suspension (that was compressed when the rear brake was released suddenly) throws off the rider up and over the high side.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the idea that a policeman counter-leans?  Any cyclist that fails to lean into a corner is going to fall over.  For a cycle rounding a corner, the centripetal force is provided by friction with the road.  The friction also produces a torque.  Leaning allows gravity to counter that torque. The line of action of the resultant force from the road (normal + friction) must pass through the center of gravity.

Comment: FWIW, all biwheel riders do in fact lean (or, at least, move the system's CM outboard)  briefly away from the desired turn direction before steering and leaning into the turn.

Comment: I will try to remember to notice that the next time I'm on my bike.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You describe it as a transient move of the *center of mass*. However, that would not necessarily set up the lean that you need. What I observe is that I move the *contact patch* of the wheel outward, which creates the required lean to flow through the corner.

Comment: @R.W.Bird Here is what I do to observe the move that sets up cornering. I go to a place where I can corner, but I can also safely abort the cornering. (For instance, an empty parking lot.)  Then I plan to corner inside some line on the ground. As I ride up to that planned corner I *postpone* the initiation as long as possible. Now: if I postpone the initiation too much I have to abort the cornering. If I initiate at the very last instant, but still just in time, then I have to put the bike into the necessary lean in a split second. Then the move to set the lean is *very noticable*.

Comment: Rider counter-lean IS required at very low-speed turns, where the wheel is pointed at the direction one needs to turn. It is taught to police, view this utube by a police instructor on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuAd8ppuafU

Comment: " Any cyclist that fails to lean into a corner is going to fall over." At higher speeds, they may fail to make the turn properly, but they won't fall over (until they hit something, anyway). The weight of the spinning wheels sees to that.